# How would using pseudonym for an article impact career? How can I still gain credit?

Tags: publications, journals, personal-name, anonymity

I am a student in the humanities and for my Masters degree dissertation I did an ethnographic research on a rather politically sensitive topic. I would love to publish an article or two about my research but, at this point, do not feel comfortable/safe revealing my identity. Since it is a thesis, it is still on the university library—although under an embargo period. I am curious about whether using a pseudonym only for journal articles I may write for this research be a good idea? If so, would it be possible to claim credit later—say in CV or when applying to positions? What would your general advice and thoughts be?

Comment: The suggested post is not the same as I want to do this only for an article or two and it would still be published under my original name in library database eventually anyways @Sursulasupportsthestrike

Comment: So you want to hide your name and at the same time make it public (to get credit). Those seem mutually exclusive aims.

Comment: @MaartenBuis not exactly. I dont want to get credit by making it public. I only want to get credit in more private occasions such as applying for a position—sending your CV. So basically I am curious whether I can "claim" that this is my work and I wrote it under another name for safety reasons in these occasions.

Comment: The technical aspects of what you are looking for are fairly simple (providing a way for you to mark the paper in a way that would allow you to prove to others that it is yours without anyone being able to identofy you from the paper itself). Unfortunately, using this in practice takes a bit of infrastructure, which is generally not there in the situations where you need it, since it is not that common of a need.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I actually think that it is actually a need for many, but since many people do not want to engage with this because there is no such infrastructure, it seems that there is less need. I already know a few people in my circle who did not turn their thesis to journal articles because of the political sensitivity of it and the potential problems it may cause under more authoritarian regimes. So, I think such infrastructure would suddenly incentivize publishing and prove that it actually was a need :D just a thought